# For loop similar to matlab

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have this for loop. Mainly, I want to print the first element (with the if) and with the else I want the whole result considering to multiply with the previous element of the for loop. 
The error is :IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Can you help me?

```
Nvec=np.linspace(1,N/2,119)
xlight=np.array([0, atan(3.2), 0, 0])
xlight_tra=transpose(xlight)
I=[]
II=[]
for i in range(len(Nvec)):
    Cmat=C[i]; x=xlight_tra[i]
    if i == 1:    
       x[:,0]=np.dot(C,xlight_tra) 
    else:
       x[:, i] =np.dot(C, x[:,i-1])
       print(x[0])
       I.append(x[0])
       print(x[:, i])
       II.append(x[:,i])
```

Comment: What do you think `xlight_tra.shape` and `x.shape` are?

Comment: If you translated this from matlab, it could help to show the original code.

Comment: for i=1:Nexit/2
    if i==1
        x(:,1) = C * [0 atan(3.2*3.14159265358/180) 0 0]';
    else
        x(:,i) = C * x(:,i-1);
    end
end

Comment: What is C? Is it defined? And, in Python, the first element in a range will be 0, not 1

Comment: And perhaps python and numpy tags would be helpful?

Comment: Should the last four lines have different indentation? I don't think they are supposed to be in the for loop?

Comment: C is a matrix 4x4

Comment: The `x=xlight_tra[i]` has no counterpart in the shown MATLAB code, so wherefrom did you derive it?

Comment: Actually, I changed in this:

for i in range(len(Nvec)):
    #Cmat=C[i]; xx=xlight_tra[i]
    if i == 1:    
       x=np.dot(C,xlight_tra) 
       #print(x)
       print(x[0:])
       #I.append(x)
    else:
       x=np.dot(C,x[:i-1])

But there is error last lineValueError: shapes (4,4) and (0,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 0 (dim 0)

Answer (score 0):

The definition `x=xlight_tra[i]` has a wrong place and a wrong value. Before the `for` loop, define `x` with the right shape:

```
x = np.empty((4, len(Nvec)))
```

Besides that, since the first index is 0, the test has to be:

```
    if i == 0:
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to store the `x` columns from each loop cycle, you could write:

```
x = xlight_tra
for i in range(len(Nvec)):
    x = np.dot(C, x)
    # do something with this cycle's "x" column
```

Comment: With my proposed changes, the code in question produces no more errors, so what do you mean by _not working_? Perhaps you should add your current code into the question post.

Comment: With your modification, I have this error: ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (1,1) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0).

Comment: The code is:
x = np.empty((4, len(Nvec)))
for i in range(len(Nvec)):
    Cmat=C[i]; xx=xlight_tra[i]
    if i == 0:    
       x=np.dot(Cmat,xx) 
       #print(x)
       print(x[:,0])

Comment: The definition `x=xlight_tra[i]` has a wrong place and a wrong value. Before the `for` loop, define `x` with the right shape:

    x = np.empty((4, len(Nvec)))
Besides that, since the first index is 0, the test has to be:

        if i == 0:

This part is ok.
` x = np.empty((4, len(Nvec)))
for i in range(len(Nvec)):
    #Cmat=C[i]; xx=xlight_tra[i]
    if i == 0:    
       x=np.dot(C,x) 
       #print(x)
       print(x[:,0])`

But the else has an error:
` else:
       x=np.dot(C,x[:i-1])`

Comment: My changes are intended for the code in your question post. The code in your comment here cannot work because the properly defined `x` is destroyed by the reassignment `x=…` in the loop; the assignments `x[:, 0]=…` and `x[:, i]=…` are to be kept.

Comment: It works like this:
x = np.empty((4, len(Nvec)))
for i in range(len(Nvec)):
    #Cmat=C[i]; xx=xlight_tra[i]
    if i == 0:    
       x=np.dot(C,x) 
       #print(x)
       print(x[:,0])
       #I.append(x)
    else:
       x[:,i]=np.dot(C,x[:,i-1])
       print(x[:,i])

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid _this_ doesn't yield correct results, not least since `x=np.dot(C,x)` operates on uninitialized `x` values.